# $\mathcal{N}=4$ Super-Yang-Mills (SYM) and the Coulomb branch?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry

$\mathcal{N}=4$ Super-Yang-Mills (SYM) theory is the maximally supersymmetric gauge theory in four dimensions and is an excellent playground to investigate new techniques in amplitude and Wilson loop calculations.

From what I could gather, $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM is usually conformal, but apparently there exists a so called "Coulomb branch" of the theory on which it is not conformal and possesses very different properties. I find it very hard to find a pedagogical introduction into what exactly this "Coulomb branch" is. Perhaps someone here knows of a good learning resource to read up on this topic? Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Therminology follows from vacuum expectation value of scalar fields in SUSY multiplet. In Coulomb phase gauge symmetry broken by vev: $SU(N) \to U^{N-1}(1)$. In suprconformal phase gauge group is not broken.

For more details, I recomend you chapter 10.2 in Bertolini lectures [Lectures on Supersymmetry](https://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/teaching.htm).

About N=4 you can consult chapter 3.1 [Supersymmetric Gauge Theories and the AdS/CFT Correspondence](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201253).